# Resharper - Possible mistaken call to GetType()

Tags: c#, resharper, ninject, log4net

When I'm configuring log4net for Ninject, Resharper raises pretty weird message "Possible mistaken call to GetType()". Any idea what this means?

```
kernel.Bind<ILog>().ToMethod(ctx => LogManager.GetLogger(ctx.Request.ParentRequest?.Service.GetType()));
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you get this warning because `ParentRequest.Service` is already a type.

Calling `GetType()` on it will probably always return something like `System.RuntimeType`, or `System.Type`.
So the warning seems quite relevant.

Comment: oh I didn't even realize Service was actually a type.. thanks!